# Fill NA values in ordered manner based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, fillna

| CustomerID | Buying_Round | Date | Purchase_amount$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2 | 01/02/2020 | 20 |
| 1001 | NaN | 07/03/2020 | 42 |
| 1001 | NaN | 01/01/2020 | 15 |
| 1002 | NaN | 01/07/2020 | 10 |
| 1002 | NaN | 07/04/2020 | 40 |
| 1002 | NaN | 12/11/2020 | 25 |
| 1003 | 1 | 22/02/2020 | 30 |
| 1003 | NaN | 14/03/2020 | 52 |
| 1003 | NaN | 10/10/2020 | 45 |

**Customer Id** is the unique number of each customer based on some confidential data. This is for a grocery store which is trying to understand how a customer tends to buy based on the round he comes in and the amount he purchases to improve inventory. **Buying round** is the the **nth** time they have come to store.

What I have done is out of this jumbled info I sorted the customer Id I can also sort the date but wanted to keep the problem as original as possible. After sorting the dates it is evident that the date influences the Buying Round and I intent to keep the buying round for calculation of Round vs purchase. Now I want to **fill the buying round in increasing order** from 1- the number of times the unique customer occur and then start from 1 again for the next customer.

Expected Output :

| CustomerID | Buying_Round | Date | Purchase_amount$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2 | 01/02/2020 | 20 |
| 1001 | 3 | 07/03/2020 | 42 |
| 1001 | 1 | 01/01/2020 | 15 |
| 1002 | 2 | 01/07/2020 | 10 |
| 1002 | 1 | 07/04/2020 | 40 |
| 1002 | 3 | 12/11/2020 | 25 |
| 1003 | 1 | 22/02/2020 | 30 |
| 1003 | 2 | 14/03/2020 | 52 |
| 1003 | 3 | 10/10/2020 | 45 |

Note: The 1001 is an example the original data have 1001 occur 12 times 1002 occur 4 times and 1003 occur 15 times with total 11000 unique customers for this year with no pattern or fixed values to determine how many number for each unique id, we sure have `value_counts` but want to work with a simpler way other than hardcoding it.

Comment: If Customer 1001 had two entries on the same date should they be the same Buying_Round number or should they be different?

Comment: There is no single entry for a single date 2 data points because the data is generated per day so if he comes 10 times the total amount is added and given round 1

Comment: This is basically happening because of cash use to buy and cashier is needed to input data manually and hence a lot of values are nan because they dont care about buying round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try [`groupby rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) after converting the `Date` column [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Buying_Round'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
        .groupby(df['CustomerID']).rank(method='dense')
        .astype(int)
)
```

Or with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount):

```
df['Buying_Round'] = (
        pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
        .sort_values()
        .groupby(df['CustomerID']).cumcount() + 1
)
```

Both Produce:

```
   CustomerID  Buying_Round        Date  Purchase_amount$
0        1001             2  01/02/2020                20
1        1001             3  07/03/2020                42
2        1001             1  01/01/2020                15
3        1002             2  01/07/2020                10
4        1002             1  07/04/2020                40
5        1002             3  12/11/2020                25
6        1003             1  22/02/2020                30
7        1003             2  14/03/2020                52
8        1003             3  10/10/2020                45
```

Comment: so I need to first sort the dates in ascending right? for the 1st method

Comment: Only with the second option. No. Rank will assign values correctly without sorting.

Comment: okay let me try both methods and see how it goes, Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Update: I tried both method dayfirst=True causes some error so I skipped that and out of the two the first one worked wonderfully. Thanks for the code